# Whither NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, datetime, nsdate

Greetings! I must be seeing things. Look at this [excerpt from the *iPhone* OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/addTimeInterval:) reference library:

> **addTimeInterval:** Returns a new NSDate
>   object that is set to a given number
>   of seconds relative to the receiver.
>   *(Deprecated. This method has been replaced by **dateByAddingTimeInterval:**.)*

However, it is nowhere to be found in the docs, nor in the headers. If I look at the Mac OS SDK, *then* I find it.

Typo? Just keep using **addTimeInterval:** after all??

Comment: Do you get a deprecated warning when compiling for iPhone? That would probably answer this fairly conclusively (at least, until the next iPhone SDK release).

Comment: No warning. Looks like a doc error after all. (Good! At least we know what's up.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually an error in the docs. `addTimeInterval:` is deprecated in Mac OS X 10.6 but not in iPhone OS 3.1.2.

You can look at the NSDate.h in MacOS and in iPhoneOS and you'll see the difference.

NSDate.h in iPhone OS

```
- (id)addTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
```

and NSDate.h in Mac OS 10.6

```
- (id)addTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6_AND_LATER;
- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5_AND_LATER;
```

Comment: Update: `-dateByAddingTimeInterval:` is fair game as of iOS 4!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo to me as I see the same thing on my system as you do. Perhaps they intended to deprecate the method as described but cut it at the last minute, with the incorrect text still in place.

Answer (score 0):

addTimeInterval is now deprecated in iOS 4.

Comment: Indeed, `-dateByAddingTimeInterval:` is now the way to go in newer iOS versions.