# dateByAddingTimeInterval method availability

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I use `dateByAddingTimeInterval` method. I checked this method on iPhone with iOS 3.1 and it's worked! But in documentation said that this method available in iOS 4.0. Why this method worked in iOS 3.1?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633228/whither-nsdate-datebyaddingtimeinterval-on-iphone-os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an error in the documentation. The header specifies:

```
- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

So it's available in 10.5, and iOS 2.0. That's why it is present in iOS 3 and later.